# Combinatorics of transformer working or failing

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

So I have 75 unique transformers that either work or fail (1 or 0 if you think of it in terms of bits) and I cant have more than half of the transformers failing.

I know that there are $2^{75}$ different possibilities of the transformers working or failing and the number of situations of more than half of them failing is $\binom{75}{38} + \binom{75}{0}$ (half failing plus scenario where all fail).

My question is, what if 25 transformers have failed (so only 13 can fail)? Is the number of failure scenarios denoted by $\binom{50}{13}$? And is this more than half of all possibilities of the storm continuing (which I am assuming is $2^{50}/2$) ?

Comment: The no. of secenaros where half or more than half fail is equal to 2^(74).....it can be considered equivalent to the half sum of binomial series......(1+x)^75 where x=1.....check it out yourself....and frame the required binomial or combinatorial expressions for the other two conditions to get the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not true that there are $\binom{75}{38}+\binom{75}0$ ways in which more than half of them fail. Since $75$ is odd, it never happens that exactly half fail, and every way in which more than half fail is matched by a way in which fewer than half fail — just change the ones to zeroes and the zeroes to ones — so in exactly half of all possible situations more than half of the transformers fail. There are $2^{75}$ possible situations, so there are $\frac12\cdot2^{75}=2^{74}$ in which more than half of the transformers fail.

If $25$ have already failed, you get total failure if at least $13$ of the remaining $50$ transformers fail. Equivalently, the system still runs as long as at most $12$ more transformers fail. This means that there are

$$\sum_{k=0}^{12}\binom{50}k$$

ways in which the system can keep running and

$$\sum_{k=13}^{50}\binom{50}k$$

in which it can fail. These two numbers of course sum to $2^{50}$, and the first is substantially smaller than the second:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{12}\binom{50}k=\sum_{k=0}^{12}\binom{50}{50-k}=\sum_{k=38}^{50}\binom{50}k\;,$$

so

$$\sum_{k=13}^{50}\binom{50}k-\sum_{k=0}^{12}\binom{50}k=\sum_{k=13}^{50}\binom{50}k-\sum_{k=38}^{50}\binom{50}k=\sum_{13}^{37}\binom{50}k\;.$$

There are *many* more ways for the system to fail than there are for it to keep running.

Comment: I eventually reached this conclusion with the help of my professor. I realized we need to sum all the possible scenarios for the transformers failing. Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Comment: A follow up if I may (unless you suggest posting as a separate question), is it possible to express the sum/difference of the combinations in terms of 2^n?

Comment: @AnasYousef: Not so far as I know: sums of the form $\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{n}k$ when $m<n$ simplify nicely only in very special cases.